# cell with imageview and button getting reused

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with many cells. In the first cell I placed a `UIImageView` to hold a pic and next to it a button that will open up a popOver.
My question is: Why is this cell is getting reused in spite of checking (cell==nil) while others are working fine.

The code is as below.

P.S. This is without using storyboard and xib only programatically.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
                         {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {


        if(indexPath.row==0)
        {

            if(self.imageView==nil)

           {            
           self.imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 2, 50, 40)];

            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];

            self.imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

           }

            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];


             if(self.chooseImage==nil)
            {

            self.chooseImage = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 10, 80, 30)];

            [self.chooseImage addTarget:self action:@selector(chooseImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            self.chooseImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            [self.chooseImage setTitle:@"CHOOSE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.chooseImage];

        }
```

Comment: what exactly you want to know.. You want to check weather your cells are getting reused or not? is that correct

Comment: my this particular cell only is getting reused others are fine , so i want to know why?

Comment: how may rows you have added to display. i.e - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: this is my code for rowInSection


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 0)
        
        return 5;
    
    if (section == 1)
        return 4;
    
    if (section == 2)
        return 4;
    
    if(section ==3)
        return 2;
    return -1;
    
}

Comment: i have many sections and its rows are all working fine but only this specific row is creating problem for me

Comment: better you attach the screen shot. That will help us.

Comment: i mean to say when i scroll my table the choose button or the uiImageview moves to the new cell anywhere

Answer (score 0):

First in code add at end of the method `return cell;` and use following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
     {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(self.imageView==nil)

           {            
           self.imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 2, 50, 40)];

            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];

            self.imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

           }
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
           if(self.chooseImage==nil)
            {

            self.chooseImage = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 10, 80, 30)];

            [self.chooseImage addTarget:self action:@selector(chooseImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            self.chooseImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            [self.chooseImage setTitle:@"CHOOSE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.chooseImage];

    }


   return cell; // this line is not in your code so add this line.

}
```

Comment: i purposely havn't wrote that line as i have many more cells below :-)

Comment: @HarshitK This is structure that how can add controls on cell :)

Comment: i guess i found the answer, i removed the (cell==nil) and all is working as i want!